# 'Object is not a function' error when trying to use Page Object with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I've got a **TypeError: object is not a function** every time I try to run my tests. Before I started to use PageObject everything was ok.

Here is my **spec.js**

```
'use strict';

var todoAppPage = require('../pages/angular.page');

describe('angularjs todo list', function () {

    var page;

    beforeEach(function () {
        page = new todoAppPage();
        page.get();
    });

    it('should add a todo task', function () {
        page.addNewTask('my first task');

        expect(page.todoList.count()).toEqual(1);
        expect(page.todoList.get(0).getText()).toEqual('my first task'); 
    });
});
```

Here is **Page Object** file

```
'use strict';

var todoAppPage = function() {

    this.newTodo = element(by.model('newTodo'));
    this.todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todos'));

    this.get = function() {
        browser.get('/');
    };

    this.addNewTask = function (taskName) {
        this.newTodo.sendKeys(taskName);
        this.newTodo.sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    };
};

module.exports = new todoAppPage();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem in the way you "export" your page object, should be:

```
module.exports = todoAppPage;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was true. But now it executes all my tests at the same time. Whole mess(

Comment: @DenisGayevskiy well, this is a separate problem. Consider making a separate question if you need help with it. Make sure you provide the details. As for this topic, close it by accepting the answer (checkbox on the left). Thank you!